# manage iframe's form submit from parent frame?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, submit

I want to change the submit function of form in iframe from the parent frame. The following code should do that, but nothing hapen. And no error shown in chrome's debugger. What is wrong?

```html
<iframe src="test.php" id="frame"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#frame").contents().find("form").submit(function(){
    return true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you are manipulating the DOM of this iframe once its contents has been loaded by wrapping your call inside a `.load` callback:

```
<iframe src="test.php" id="frame"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#frame').load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('form').submit(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: any cross-browser success on this one? seems too good to be true. Always seemed like a security issue to me. You seriously saying you can manipulate the DOM of an iframe via parent page's JS? Either this has limits or my brain just exploded...

Comment: @3Dom, this will only work if the iframe src property is pointing to the same domain as the parent domain. If you have an iframe pointing to google.com for example you can of course forget about manipulating its contents.